# Coolant type for 1977 Diesel

Tags: coolant, diesel

I have a marine 1977 Perkins T6.354 6 cyl, 6 liter turbo diesel.  There are different types of coolant available and I've done significant research into this question and have not found a clear answer.

Most of the diesel information available pertains to modern wet sleeve diesels and they recommend the modern D-6210 spec, which come in different flavors (HOAT, OAT, NOAT).  These formulations have improvements around corrosion and pitting over "traditional coolant" that is D-3306 spec.

All the antifreeze at the parts shop are D-3306, with one bottle of 6210.

This is a dry sleeve engine with probably an old head gasket. My concern is the newer 6210 may not be compatible with it. The original spec in the manual recommended an outdated formulation that is no longer available.

Should I use D-6210 or D-3306?

Thanks,
RR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an antifreeze product that holds both certs and is Perkins certified?
Zerex G-05.  http://content.valvoline.com/pdf/Zerex_G-05_AFC_Technical_Bulletin.pdf.   We use it in many older engines were the older product is no longer made but the newer spec is not appropriate. It has not caused compatibility issues. It is a nitrated product which helps with cylinder liner cavitation, the toughest issue with diesels and coolant.

Head gaskets have not been the primary problem with the new spec organic acid coolants, it has been damage to plastic parts in cooling systems.

If you need more info contact the Zerex help desk.

Comment: The G-05 is the same conclusion I came to.  Thanks.